# How to conditionally execute Reactor's Mono/Flux supplier operator?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How to conditionally execute the [`then(Mono<T>)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) operator?

I have a method that returns `Mono<Void>`. It can also return an error signal. I want to use the `then` operator (or any other operator), only when the previous operation completes without an error signal.

Can someone help me to find the right supplier operator?

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono.just("GOOD_SIGNAL")//It can also be a BAD_SIGNAL
                .flatMap(s -> firstMethod(s))
                .then(secondMethod())
                .subscribe()
        ;
    }
```

```java
    private static Mono<String> secondMethod() {
        //This method call is only valid when the firstMethod is success
        return Mono.just("SOME_SIGNAL");
    }
```

```java
    private static Mono<Void> firstMethod(String s) {
        if ("BAD_SIGNAL".equals(s)) {
            Mono.error(new Exception("Some Error occurred"));
        }

        return Mono
                .empty()//Just to illustrate that this function return Mono<Void>
                .then();
    }
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I want to underline that Reactor's Mono/Flux (will consider Mono next) have the following conditioning operators (at least what I know):

- [`Mono#switchIfEmpty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-)
- [`Mono#defaultIfEmpty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defaultIfEmpty-T-)
- combination of [`Mono#filter`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and some other supplier operator (e.g. [`Mono#flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-))

The second point is that [`Mono#then`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-):

> ignore element from this Mono and transform its completion signal into the emission and completion signal of a provided Mono. An error signal is replayed in the resulting Mono.

So it means that `then` is about to return the value (empty or provided) despite what was before it.

Considering all of that, your solution would look something like that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono.just("GOOD_SIGNAL")//It can also be a BAD_SIGNAL
                .flatMap(s -> firstMethod(s))
                .switchIfEmpty(secondMethod())
                .doOnError(...)//handle you error here
                .subscribe();
    }

private static Mono<String> secondMethod() {
     //This method call is only valid when the firstMethod is success
     return Mono.just("SOME_SIGNAL");
}

private static Mono<Void> firstMethod(String str) {
    return Mono.just(str)
               .filter(s -> "BAD_SIGNAL".equals(s))
               .map(s -> new Exception("Some Error occurred: "+s))
               .flatMap(Mono::error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`then` propagates an error in its source, so it covers this aspect. From what I understand, the reason you cannot use `flatMap` instead of `then` is that the source is empty, due to `firstMethod()`. In that case, combine `defer()` and `then()` to achieve the laziness you seek:

```
Mono.just("GOOD_SIGNAL")//It can also be a BAD_SIGNAL
    .flatMap(s -> firstMethod(s))
    .then(Mono.defer(this::secondMethod))
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: why defer is needed in this way?

Comment: it will prevent eager execution of method2, only running it if the source completes first